# Is 200ms slow for a graphql query to resolve?

Tags: performance, graphql

I am trying to decide whether I need to refactor the graphql queries for a mobile app I am building.  Currently, the main query is taking 1.81s to resolve, which seems too slow.  So I am breaking it into multiple queries depending on what level of nesting you are viewing in-app.

I'm using Insomnia to measure the amount of time each query takes to resolve.  I am trying to understand what an "acceptable" resolve time is for each query.  Should I be aiming for <200ms, <500ms, <1s?  I realize this is a broad question, but just trying to get a sense of what good devs aim for in terms of millisecond response times.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you are doing on the server, the database you are calling, the number of objects queried...

Also if your API is running on Raspberry it won't respond in the same time as on Zen/Xeon and also not every Xeon is the same between VPS providers.

It's a *too* broad question in my opinion. You can share some details on the environment and the type of queries/processing you do, then maybe someone can share their approximate results based on this info.